# Rails Carrierwave acessing parent model from within a version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm trying to create a version on my carrierwave uploader that checks to see whether it's parent model has some data on how to resize and crop the image, if not do a default resize to fill. I've been trying to reference the model as demonstrated here: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

If I run the version code like this:

```
version :title do
      if model.dimensions_hash["title"]
            process :image_crop => [model.dimensions_hash["title"], 960, 384]
      else
            process :resize_to_fill => [960, 384]
      end
  end
```

I get this error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `model' for #<Class:0x007f9eae7cfed0>
    from /Users/RyanKing/Sites/test/app/uploaders/page_image_uploader.rb:45:in `block in <class:PageImageUploader>'
```

Line 45 being `process :image_crop => [model.dimensions_hash["title"], 960, 384`

---

If the if statement returns true why does the line 45 return an error? Am I referencing the model incorrectly?

I found a similar problem here but wasn't able to adapt it to my situation. [Passing a parameter to the uploader / accessing a model's attribute from within the uploader / letting the user pick the thumbnail size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713628/passing-a-parameter-to-the-uploader-accessing-a-models-attribute-from-within)

Comment: The model variable points to the instance object the uploader is attached to. do you underrstand it?

Comment: Yes so it should point to the model with `mount_uploader :image, PageImageUploader` right? Why would `model` be undefined?

Comment: @RyanKing error ie because model is instance variable/object of ur uploader but the conditions is frame in context of `Uploader` i.e `Class.new([Your Uploader]).model => hence `undefined` because it something like this Class.new([Your Uploader]).new(mount_as,mount_something).model` check over [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb#L110)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you are right `model` method wont be available because `version` is a

class method and whereas `model` is instance method of uploader

but there are way to get them

if you check the `link` that I have attached in the mail the all that is define inside block are `class_eval` so taking that into account you can modify your code like this

```
version :title do
  process :image_crop => [960, 384],:if => :has_title?
  process :resize_to_fill => [960, 384] ,:if => :has_not_title?

  def has_title?
     model.dimensions_hash["title"].present?
  end

  def has_not_title?
    not(has_title?)
  end
end
```

Hope this help

Comment: I have tried to do something like this but failed: `process resize_to_limit: [2048, 2048] , if model.attachmentable_type = "Page"`. It seems that `model` cannot be accessed this way. I get `undefined local variable or method `model' for AttachmentUploader:Class`

Comment: @W.M. I am facing this issue, have you found a solution?